# Disable Shindig Caching

Tags: google-gadget, apache-shindig

How can I disable caching in shindig? I tried passing nocache=1 parameter in the request. It disabled shindig caching but added Pragma: no-cache and Cache-Control: no-cache to the response.

I don't want to disable browser caching but just shindig caching. What is the right way to do so.

Any thoughts? Ideas?

Comment: Which URL are you passing the nocache parameter to?  And what do you now want cached?  There are many caches in Shindig.

Comment: I am adding nocache parameter to the proxy url i.e. https://<ip-address>/test-app/gadgets/proxy/container=shell-default&refresh=-1&nocache=1&gadget=XXXX/https://<ip-address>/<rest-endpoint-for-a-icon>

I don't want the icon returned by server to be cached by Shindig but  only browser to cache it.

Answer (score 0):

You could disable [content rewriting](http://opensocial-resources.googlecode.com/svn/spec/trunk/Core-Gadget.xml#rfc.section.5) for all or some URLs in your gadget which will cause Shindig to not rewrite those URLs to go through the content proxy.

Comment: According to my requirements, I need my request to go through proxy.

Comment: The only purpose of this proxy is to cache resources for the gadget.  If you don't want them cached then there is no need to use the proxy.